# CakePHP Inflector slug issue

Tags: cakephp, inflector

When I use:

```
Inflector::slug("My Lovely & long slug");
```

On my local server I get:

```
My_Lovely_long_slug
```

When I use it on my server I get:

```
Lo_l_lo_lu
```

What gives? This issue is also affecting all my cache names which I assume are using the Inflector class. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Going to use a workaround function for what i need but it still screws with my cache entries:

Answer (score 4):

looks like to different versions of cake? ive seen this reported before but dont have any references for you. Tested on my server for ~ 1.3.6/7 and it works as expected.

if the versions of cake are the same try and do a 'git bisect' which will give you an answer pretty quick

update:

seems to do with your PCRE libraries installed on the server that are older etc. give them an update and all should be fine

Comment: I'm using cake 1.3.8 both local and server side.

Answer (score 2):

So I made my own slug for now.

```
function permalink ($string = '',$length = false)
{
    $string = strtolower($string); // All lowercase
    $string = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9]/',' ', $string); // Remove garbage
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/','_', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('|-+|','_', $string);
    if ($length) $string = substr($string,0,$length); // Limit string length?
    $parsed = trim($string,'_'); // Trim pre and post trailing delims
    return $parsed;
}
```